# Event ID 494 - Database recovery failed with error -1216 because it encountered references to a database

Tags: exchange-2003

Setup is SBS 2003 all patched up fine. This morning i find i can not log onto OWA (503 Service Unreliable). A little trouble shooting and i see i can not mount the Mailbox store. Poking aroundin Event Viewer, the first sign of trouble i see is:

Information Store (7020) First Storage Group: Database recovery failed with error -1216 because it encountered references to a database, 'D:\Exchange\priv1.edb', which is no longer present. The database was not brought to a Clean Shutdown state before it was removed (or possibly moved or renamed). The database engine will not permit recovery to complete for this instance until the missing database is re-instated. If the database is truly no longer available and no longer required, procedures for recovering from this error are available in the Microsoft Knowledge Base or by following the "more information" link at the bottom of this message.

There has been no attempt to recover the exchange db, and all i can think of was maybe a dirty shutdown. I'm not sure how to proceed as most online guides seem to think this is caused by an incorrect db restore.

Any ideas?

Comment: I managed to fix it using this guide: http://blog.checkoutmycards.com/2007/08/26/how-i-recovered-exchange-server-2003/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://blog.comc.com/2007/08/26/how-i-recovered-exchange-server-2003/) is the guide I ended up following, posted below for posterity (as blog post seemed to have since moved):

> Made a backup of the entire “G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA\” directory
> Found this article about eseutil
> From “G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\bin” I ran the following command.
>
> - eseutil.exe /r E00 /l”G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA”
>
> This complained about priv1.edb being corrupt, so I ran the following commands to repair and defragment the edb files.
>
> - eseutil.exe /p “G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA\priv1.edb”
> - eseutil.exe /d “G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA\priv1.edb”
> - eseutil.exe /p “G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA\pub1.edb”
> - eseutil.exe /d “G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA\pub1.edb”
>
> This fixed the corruption, but when tried to restart the “Microsoft Exchange Information Store” service, I got this error in the event log.
>
> Information Store (3600) First Storage Group: Database recovery failed with error -1216 because it encountered references to a database, ‘G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA\priv1.edb’, which is no longer present. The database was not brought to a Clean Shutdown state before it was removed (or possibly moved or renamed). The database engine will not permit recovery to complete for this instance until the missing database is re-instated. If the database is truly no longer available and no longer required, please contact PSS for further instructions regarding the steps required in order to allow recovery to proceed without this database.
>
> This was very confusing because the file actually was present, but it turns out that you need to run a recovery to bring the database back to a clean state. So, I ran the recover command again.
>
> - eseutil.exe /r E00 /l”G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA”
>
> This time it complained with the following error.
> Operation terminated with error -1216 (JET_errAttachedDatabaseMismatch, An  outstanding database attachment has been detected at the start or end of recovery,   but database is missing or does not match attachment info) after 130.0 seconds.
>
> This was the result of having to run the repair command without doing a clean  shutdown. To resolve that issue I had to run the same recover command with the /i switch to ignore the inconsistencies.
>
> - eseutil.exe /r E00 /l”G:\Program Files\Exchsrver\MDBDATA” /i
>
> Finally I had to mount the mailbox and public folder stores by doing the following.
>
> - Open Server Management (Start -> Server Management)
> - Expand the Advanced Management node
> - Expand the  (Exchange) node
> - Expand the Servers node
> - Expand the  node
> - Expand the First Storeage Group node
> - Right-click Mailbox Store () node
> - Click the Mount Store node
> - Right-click Public Folder Store () node
> - Click the Mount Store node

Answer (score 1):

When you have a tough time in Exchange Server while opening or loading files of Exchange Server then it's mandatory that use proper tool to remove the corruption issue from Exchange Database otherwise your data may get corrupt at deeper level. [Exchange Database Recovery Failed 1216](http://www.convertedbtopst.com/exchange-database-recovery-failed-1216.html) error is one of those corruption error which disturb the user due to either files missing issue or file replacement. But if you pick out tool, you can easily cope up with error issues in a flash. This tool follows an advanced algorithm to detect the errors and then removal of all of them. Exchange database recovery failed with error 1216 is not a big problem if you have our tool in your hand. Demo version of the tool is available at Free of Cost. Just download it so that you will get to know the real potential of the software. http://www.convertedbtopst.com/

Answer (score 0):

To fix Dirty Shutdown error, you need transaction logs that were being processed at the time of the failure to recover the database.

It means transactions were either partially committed to Exchange database or it is required to bring back your database to a consistent state.

You need to use Eseutil soft recovery (eseutil /r) on the database. the command will replay log files, it can help only in case of minor corruption.

If database is still in Dirty Shutdown state, then perform hard recovery (eseutil /p). Before using eseutil read [Microsoft Docs1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/repairing-exchange-databases-with-eseutil-when-and-how/ba-p/610276) and [Doc2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53373.exchange-troubleshooting-role-of-transaction-logs-in-recovery.aspx) thoroughly.